# Jquery contents().find changing attar from ajax call issues

Tags: jquery

Hey guys I'm having an issue I hope I can explain it so I can find a solution. So I have a page called editor.php that pulls in a page like so with Jquery

```
    $(function() {
        $("#editor_test").load("test.php?vfID=<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>"); 
    });
```

Which is then displayed in a div

```
    <div id="editor_test"></div>
```

In the test.php page I have a div area that holds information from the database, next to the information is an edit button

```
    <img src="images/btn_edit.gif" border="0" id="SL_editButton1" class="editButton" />
```

What I want to do is change that button to a different button once that edit button is clicked. The id's are all dynamic so editor.php knows which area to affect. I have tried to do this...

```
    function doSLoad(){         
        $("#editor_test").contents().find("#SL_editButton<?php echo $sl_result['id']; ?>").attr('src',('images/btn_edit_b.gif'));
    }
```

I tried to run doSLoad on DOM ready, it will change the button is I trigger it in a different function that updates the div area in test.php with something like this.

```
    $("#ubTitle").keyup(sl_update);
```

ubTitle is the field name in the editor.php page that allows you to update the text. Just like StackOverflow is doing as I type this in...

Once you make a change on every keyup this runs

```
function sl_update(){       
    var ubTitle = $("#ubTitle").val();
    $("#vf_editor").contents().find("#Title<?php echo $sl_result['orderid']; ?>").html(ubTitle);
    doSLoad();
}
```

If I trigger doSLoad on keyup the image changes and all is well, but I want it to change once the page has been loaded not when I start making changes, I have tried all sorts of ways

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    doSLoad();
})
```

that didn't work, I tried to do it on focus and force the focus on the text field,

```
 $("#ubTitle").focus(sl_update);
```

it didn't work.

Any help to get this image to change unload would be greatly appreciated, thanks everyone.

Comment: Is there a reason you do `$("#editor_test").contents().find` instead of just `$("#editor_test").find`?

Comment: Updated thanks Musa...

Answer (score 1):

> What I want to do is change that button to a different button once that edit button is clicked.

You have multiple buttons, but they all have a unique class, so this code should do what I've quoted above as your goal:

```
$('#editor_test').on('click', '.editButton', function(e) {
    $(this).attr('src', 'images/btn_edit_b.gif');
});
```

Comment: Thanks Anthony works if I put it in the test page, but need it to load from the main page. using setTimeout to give the page just a bit longer to load the ajax fixed it issue.

Comment: @JohnRamon If you stick it immediately before your call to `$('#editor_test').load(...);` (i.e. still inside the `$(function() {`) it should work in the main page.

Answer (score 0):

In jquery *load* function you can add a callback to inform that the page has been loaded.

```
$("#div").load("url",function(data){
      //page loaded
});
```

Comment: Tried didn't work but I did find a solution.  setTimeout(function(){doSLoad();}, 100); seems it wasn't quite ready to find that...

Comment: Great..please share !